# How To change Layer color

Tags: colors, photoshop, color-scheme

I am trying to change selected layer color just by paint bucket tools . when I apply color to layer it does not change to color which I am applying to it .

Or sometimes when it changes the color it will mix color to the layer like if layer is in red and I want to apply yellow color it will mix red + yellow .

I want to know how can I use paint bucket tools or other tools to get desired output color .

Comment: Do you have any code to share yet, so that we can help you fix it?

Comment: @lenz this is in photoshop. i have created square which is in #00FFFF Color now. i want to change it to #7AC144. but paint bucket tool is not able to change this layer color.when i use color replacement tool with #7AC144 color output layer comes with color #8fd659 not #7AC144

Comment: Are you using the GUI or are you scripting for Photoshop? If this isn't a programming question, you probably won't get help here. See the suggestions in the `photoshop` tag description.

Comment: Use the `Edit` menu, then `Fill`.